# Dúvidas de como funciona o RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, twitter-api

Estou a fazer uma aplicação que irá consumir o alguns dados do Twitter. Estou usando a [biblioteca](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries) recomendada pelos desenvolvedores da API, como minha aplicação é apenas para consumir API eu uso apenas JavaScript e jQuery, então uso a biblioteca [TwitterJSClient](https://github.com/BoyCook/TwitterJSClient).

Nessa biblioteca, logo no começo do arquivo `/TwitterJSClient/lib/Twitter.js` tem o seguinte código:

```
var OAuth = require('oauth').OAuth;
var qs = require('qs');
```

Após analisar sua estrutura de pastas e arquivos, vi que ele tem alguns diretórios nomeados de `oauth` e `qs`.

Ao anexar esse projeto ao meu, de primeira não funciona porque essas funções não pertencem ao JavaScript e nem ao jQuery, ou seja, *undefined*.

O pouco que sei do RequireJS, é que ele carrega arquivos para dentro de outro, viabilizando o uso do mesmo. Porém, mesmo depois de usar o RequireJS (versão ~2.1.14) que instalei via [Bower](http://bower.io) (`bower install requirejs`) o projeto não funciona como deveria.

O Erro que dá é o seguinte:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "oauth" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
```

Alterei o código do projeto para:

```
var OAuth = require(['oauth']).OAuth;
var qs = require(['qs']);
```

E o resultado muda para:

```
GET http://192.168.0.22:9000/oauth.js 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught Error: Script error for: oauth
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
GET http://192.168.0.22:9000/qs.js 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught Error: Script error for: qs
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

**Estrutura de diretórios e arquivos (parcial):**

```
Project/
  app/
    images/
    scripts/
      TwitterJSClient/
        lib/
          Twitter.js
        node_modules/
          .bin/
          jasmine-node/
          oauth/
            examples/
            lib/
              _ultils.js
              oauth.js
              oauth2.js
              sha1.js
            tests/
            index.js
          qs/
            test/
            index.js
        test/
        index.js
      main.js
    styles/
    index.html
  bower_components/
    requirejs/
      require.js
  node_modules/
  test/
```

Alguém pode me indicar um caminho para usar o [TwitterJSClient](https://github.com/BoyCook/TwitterJSClient) em meu projeto?

Comment: Pode colocar asua estrututa de pastas e o `oauth.js` aqui?

Comment: Coloquei, mas não sei muito usar a Markdown. Se puder arrumar eu agradeço!

Comment: Já testou a dar a path completa no require? o erro que lhe deu aponta para isso: `http://192.168.0.22:9000/oauth.js 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Acontece que eu não sei usar bem o require. Na verdade não sei se ele está tentando pegar o arquivo oauth.js ou todo o diretório oauth. E como eu uso o Yeaoman o path raiz de desenvolvimento diverge do path raiz de produção. Acho que não é legal colocar path completa.

Comment: Pois o require assume que o ficheiro é `.js` e aí não precisa de colocar a extenção do ficheiro. Teste no browser a path completa a ver se encontra o ficheiro... tipo `http://192.168.0.22:9000/lib/oauth.js`

Comment: mudei o diretório para "scripts/TwitterJSClient/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth" e deu certo. Porém, dentro desse arquivo há outros require para outros arquivos e também uma função não definida chamada de EXPORTS.

Comment: Notei que o require que instalei via bower sempre busca arquivos a partir da path "app/". Será que não preciso fazer alguma alteração sobre isso, se é que é possivel?

Answer (score 1):

Require é uma função *builtin* do Node que serve para incluir modulos que estão em outros arquivos Js.
Ele funciona lendo o arquivo passado em parametro, executando e então retornando o objecto *Exports*

Fonte: [O que é Require?](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/what-is-require)

Sobre a forma como o node descobre os modulos, ele sempre começa da pasta local ao projeto node_modules, depois se não encontrar procura na instalação global do node.

Comment: Mediante sua explicação, acha que devo migrar o diretório node_modules que se encontra dentro do biblioteca TwitterJSClient/ para o diretório node_modules do meu projeto app/  !??

Comment: Se você tiver utilizando o node puro ou yeoman, bower ou outro gerenciador de pacotes não deveria precisar se preocupar com esse diretório pois ele será gerenciado por uma ferramenta dessas. Os problemas normalmente surgem quando você copia na mão os arquivos. [https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html)

Comment: O problema é que eu preciso baixar a library do twitter e anexa-la à meu projeto. Esta library está no Github e não no npm. Logo tenho que colocar 'na mão'. Então em que pasta devo colocá-la e como referencio ela no meu projeto, se é que precisa?

Comment: use bower se o seu projeto estiver utilizando, senão o jeito é colocar na mão.